# Vaadin-view scope (customization for Tagetik) and memory leak

Tags: spring, memory-leaks, scope, garbage-collection, vaadin

I noticed a problem of memory leaking and I'll show you with this example:

I have an object of class Mother instanciated by Spring with scope vaadin-view;

in the constructor of Mother there is an other object Son instanciated with "new".

I don't understand why the Son object is never released after Garbage Collection, even when I manually launch GC at Mother closure, whilst Mother object is correctly released.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Clearly some other object(s) holds a reference to Son in addition to Mother. You need to inspect your code more to find that out.

Comment: I tried to instantiate Son object with a spring bean with scope vaadin-view e no memory leak is detected, so there is clearly a problem with "new" instantiation, but I don't understand what

Comment: Do you have a static variable somewhere?

Comment: I have no static variables

Comment: ```
even when I manually launch GC at Mother closure
```

I assume you come from a different language like C++ and put code into the `finalize` method. This is not guaranteed to execute even on program exit.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/401554/what-to-use-instead-of-finalize-in-java might be useful.

Comment: The program is written with Java.  I have a method that handle the closure of my vaadin View. In that method I put the System.gc() command and I compared two situation:
- when I leave "new" instantiation of Son object into Mother;
- when I instantiate Son with a bean with scope vaadin-view;
I noticed that in the first case Son object is not destroyed at GC; in the second case Son object is correctly destroyed at GC